# Feature without layer?

Tags: qgis, editing

I'm working in QGIS. I've created a new .shp file with intentions to make a line that I would buffer. I had toggle editing on and clicked add feature and started to draw and then buffered. The buffer did not work so I erased the new .shp file to try again but the the previous line is still there and doesn't belong to any layer. How can I erase this feature?

[image]

Comment: try clicking on clear selection (2 to the right of currently selected button)

Comment: Did you finished creating new line feature while editing (right click), and save the edits?

Comment: What do you mean by 'erase'? You can't delete it via explorer when it's still opened in QGIS, did you remove from the layer Tree via right-click|remove or so? And what was wrong with the buffering?

Comment: Thanks @OtoKalab, I just toggled editing on, then right-clicked to finish and clicked cancel.

Comment: @Evan I posted my comment as an answer, so if it solved your problem you can accept it

Answer (score 1):

You have to **finish**  creating new line feature with `right click` while editing, and than save edits.